# Decryption issue in python using AES algorithm

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycrypto

I am building website in python flask & using AES algorithm of pycrypto library. In sign up web page, I am saving encrypted pwd & encrypted key in text file. In login page, I am comparing entered pwd with decrypted pwd,using below code

```
def decryption(encryptedString,key_from_file):
    PADDING = '{'
    DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)
    #Key is FROM the printout of 'secret' in encryption
    #below is the encryption.
    encryption = encryptedString
    key = key_from_file
    cipher = AES.new(key) #### error comes here 
    decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encryption)
    return decoded

def login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html')
    if  request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        d2 = pandas.read_csv("Employee_Info.txt",header=0)
        search_id = d2[d2['email'] == username]
        pdb.set_trace()
        if search_id.empty:
            error = "username does not exists"
            return render_template('login.html', error = error)
        else:
            pwd_from_file=search_id.iloc[0]['pwd']
            key_from_file=search_id.iloc[0]['key']

            if decryption(pwd_from_file,key_from_file) == password:
                print "matching password"
            else:
                print "mismatch"
```

but I am getting error as `ValueError: AES key must be 16,24 or 32 bytes long.`

Text file has below fields:

```
id,email,pwd,key
qq,qq,h4vvEPuVNwjw22yJKz8QGg==,xéðjŸ¸AOÝ¬‡
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the key in raw Unicode bytes, so there is likely a serialization/deserialization error. Encode the raw key bytes in hexadecimal or Base64 before storing in the file, and then convert back to raw before initializing your cipher.

**Note: Storing the key in the credentials data store is *very bad*, and *encrypting* passwords for credential verification is also *very bad*.** Look at [Why should I hash passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36833/why-should-i-hash-passwords) and [How to securely hash passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) for more information.